# Accused of "stealing rep" because I felt the answer was belittling and uncommunicative

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[Emulation for ERB extention -%> for the purpose of unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30578600/438992)

And the answer I had an issue with:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30578842/438992

> > I've been able to replicate the problem in irb as so:
>
> irb is worthless in so many ways, but especially this one.  Do you really think that irb output *clarifies* your problem?  For me, I can tell you that it is unreadable garbage.
>
> Next, can you point to any documentation that says `-%>` is a legal ERB tag? Or, do you think you can just make up tags as you go along and have ruby understand them?

And yes, I called him a douche after he lashed out.

I didn't believe the answer was appropriate in tone or content. Am I totally off base here? I thought SO was trying to be a nicer place, then I find myself on the receiving end of this.

Was I out of line in providing a reason for the exhibited behavior and calling out the tone?

Comment: _"And yes, I called him a douche after he lashed out."_ With +100k you actually should know better.

Comment: Just flag and move on. Don't throw in your own insults. I don't care about how much rep anyone has. It's just not worth it. Everyone gets frustrated. (But I also love SO drama.)

Comment: Letting someone know that they are acting inappropriately is actually a good thing but agree with @πάνταῥεῖ . It should be done in a more polite way even if the other person *is* being a douche. But his "answer" *is* better suited as a comment with a little better tone to it. Also, *"I have zero power to delete answers"* isn't entirely true as you can vote to delete but, as you said, that didn't happen here.

Comment: Too many answers posted as comments.  Too many comments unhelpful here.

Comment: That was an inappropriate edit, IMO; @πάνταῥεῖ altered the *meaning* of your post, which is destructive.

Comment: _@DaveNewton_ Rolled back. I was adding a comment for the OP, but the answer was deleted beforehand, and re-appeared as a comment. Also you should ping @pnuts specifically?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No worries, I meant to respond to pnuts anyway :)

Comment: _@DaveNewton_ Well, this might need 2 pings, one for @pnuts and another one for me (to trigger the justified rollback). Or just rollback yourself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I still wish we could have multiple @ in comments, but hey.

Comment: _@DaveNewton_ "I still wish we could have multiple @ in comments ..."_ Most of these could, and should, be solved by addressing multiple (and different) comments. You may have noticed my trickery of _@emphasis_ used in my comments ;-) ... (won't work to address two non-op's at the same time though)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Maybe in general, but there have been enough times I've wanted to include multiple parties in a comment that I'd still like the capability. YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading [the original answer you're asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578600/emulation-for-erb-extention-for-the-purpose-of-unittests/30578842#30578842), the tone certainly seems significantly more confrontational and aggressive than there's any reason for. Also, since it's phrased entirely in the form of aggressive questions, it's extremely hard to tell that there's even an attempt at providing the real answer - putting the hostile tone problems aside, if I ran across that in the VLQ queue, I very possibly might have read it as falling into the "Requesting Clarification or Critiquing" catergory.

Resorting to name-callling may have been inadvisable, and you definitely should know better. However, it definitely doesn't seem like a high quality answer to me. I agree that it is inappropriate in both tone and form.